# Set Max number of Queries to specific database user in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way that a database user can be restricted to do one connection to a database and only one query at time? -In SQL Server 2008 R2 -

Example 1:

- Database: database_1
- Username: some_user
- Password: some_pass

First Connection to database_1:

- Connection: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1
- ...Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1

Second Connection to database_1:

- Connection: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2
- ...Failed to connect: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2

User `some_user` trying to execute some query:

Query 1:

```
select * 
from table1 
join ,...,join tableN
```

Example 2:

- Database: database_1
- Username: some_user
- Password: some_pass

First Connection to database_1:

- Connection: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1
- ...Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1

Second Connection to database_1:

- Connection: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2
- ...Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2

User `some_user` trying to execute some query by using connection: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1

Query1:

```
 select * from table1 join ,...,join tableN
```

Result: executed... N records returned

User now tries to execute another query by using connection: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2

Query2:

```
select * from table1 join , ... , join tableN
```

Result: not executed... can't executed more than once query at a time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create any access policy you like using [logon triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx):

> You can use logon triggers to audit and control server sessions, such as by tracking login activity, restricting logins to SQL Server, or **limiting the number of sessions for a specific login**.

See the link for an example. If you limit a user to only one connection at a time then you have effectively limited the user to only one query at a time since, for all practical purposes, a connection can only run one query (w/o going into [MARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx) details).

A related concept you need to be aware is the [Resource Governor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx), which allows you to limit the resource a user can consume by assigning user sessions to specific workloads and limiting the workload resource allocation. Again, see the link for details and examples.